# django admin panel data

Tags: django, django-models

Hi Team i have a written code in admin.py. At this time i am getting urls and other feilds . what i want as url can be duplicate for ex i have google url but each url consist if different crud operations . what i want is grouping . Please advise how we can do that.

class UrlAccessAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ('method', 'clickable_url', 'has_access', 'get_roles', 'description')
list_filter = ('method',)
search_fields = ['url', ]
list_per_page= 15

```
def get_roles(self, obj):
    return obj.role_list if obj.role_list != 'ALL' else 'All Roles'

def clickable_url(self, obj):
    url_length = 50 
    if len(obj.url) > url_length:
        truncated_url = f'{obj.url[:url_length]}...'
    else:
        truncated_url = obj.url

    return mark_safe(f'<a href="{obj.url}" target="_blank">{truncated_url}</a>')

clickable_url.short_description = 'URL'
```

admin.site.register(UrlAccess, UrlAccessAdmin)